# How to redirect to an URL by a re-routed URL in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, routes

I have the following route:

```
$route['new-products'] = 'products/latest';
```

I want somewhere in my controller to use somthing like this:

```
//this will go to /new-products
redirect_route('products/latest');
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes. I have tried to extend `CI_Route` to get the key of a route by value defined in `routes.php`, but i coudn't get it.

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
redirect('products/latest');
```

or

```
redirect('new-products');
```

> make sure `index.php` is removed from URL

Comment: This is work because it is routed to its controller and method, but i dont want to be accesible that page by 2 different URL. I would like to finally URL to be exwebsite/new-products

Comment: @Dumitru If this help please **[Mark it as ACCEPT**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Hence [**VOTE UP** will lead my TAG count](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    redirect(site_url('new-products'));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this rule in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule    "^/products/latest"  "new-products"  [R]
```

[Docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html#old-to-new-extern).

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect with this:

```
redirect(set_url('new-products'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the url helper adding it in you autoload.php or you can add it in your actual php file where you are gonna use it.

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

After this you can redirect by

```
redirect('controller/action');
```

This redirect to the base_url with your extension. If you want to use nice urls without index.php, you have do clear the index_page in config.php.